# Google Calendar.Insert API returning 400 'required'

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create a calendar via the Google javascript API. OAuth authentication is working fine : I'm able to get a list of calendars using:

```
gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list();
```

However, when I try to create a calendar with:

```
gapi.client.calendar.calendars.insert(
{
    "summary": "A New Calendar",
    "description": "Generated by Ben",
    "timezone" : "Australia/Sydney"
});
```

I get:

```
{
  "error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required",
  "data": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required"
   }
  ]
 },
 "id": "gapiRpc"
}
```

In [doco for other APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/urlshortener/v1/getting_started.html#errors) it shows this response, but with a list of the required arguments that are missing.

Is there any way to determine what 'required' parameter I'm missing? I've tested it with the [API Explorer](https://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=calendar&_v=v3&_m=calendars.insert) and my parameters appear to work fine.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Finally figured this out. The properties need to be in a 'resource' object:

```
gapi.client.calendar.calendars.insert(
{
    "resource" :
    {"summary": "A New Calendar",
    "description": "Generated by Ben",
    "timezone" : "Australia/Sydney"}
});
```

The doco doesn't mention this, but if you look at the response to the initial call to `gapi.auth.authorize` you'll find JSON describing the entire API for the scope you've specified.

Answer (score 0):

But I could normally create a new calendar using `POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars` API according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendars/insert):

```
body = {
    'summary': 'calendarSummary',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
}
```